# Are word requests for jargon-specific terms on-topic?

Tags: support, on-topic-off-topic

I want to ask if there is an equivalent antonym for the term, "portable app", but this term is specific to software.

Would this be on-topic for EL&U or should I ask it instead on Super User?

(I already posted on SE Meta; they referred me here. I also read [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/questions-asking-for-technical-terms-jargon) post which went a bit deeper into the topic, and although certainly an answer was chosen, in my opinion both of the two answers had good points, hence my uncertainty.)

Comment: I don't see the difference between this question and the prior one. If you still have uncertainty about the prior question, edit that one (you can unaccept answers if you want).

Comment: How the hell can I unaccept answers? That's not my question.

Comment: I was confusing the question you linked to with [your  own prior question on this topic](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7010/55623).

Comment: Okay, thanks. There is a distinct difference: that question deals with *definitions*; this question deals with *words*. In other words, I'm asking here about a question asking whether or not an antonym exists, not about one regarding the nature of their the definitions. It is a distinct, albeit slight, distinction.